# Can different source files produce the same hash value?

Tags: hash-function

It is often said in judicial opinions and legal briefs that the hash value derived from a file is like a fingerprint that uniquely corresponds to the source file. While this may be true in a practical sense, I question whether it is literally true. It is my understanding that the hash function is a many-to-one function, and therefore multiple source files could produce the same hash value. I understand that the utility of the hash function is that making a small change to a source file does not result in a small change to hash value derived from that file.

Comment: If any of the answers did address your question, you can accept it via the green checkmark on the left. If not, I reckon asking  the 4 answerers for details or clarifications is the best option.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is my understanding that the hash function is a many-to-one
>   function, and therefore multiple source files could produce the same
>   hash value.

An arbitrary file, with many million bytes is mapped to a few bytes typically. So there ought to be collisions.

For a good cryptographic hash function it is however hard to compute a message which results in a given has value. See e.g. [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).

> In the legal community, hash codes are generally taken as being unique
>   identifiers.

Note that this is a mapping from a huge set (e.g. $2^{8\cdot 10^6}$ possible elements) to still a very large set (e.g. $2^{160}$ elements).

> I understand that the utility of the hash function is that making a
>   small change to a source file does not result in a small change to
>   hash value derived from that file.

It should result in a noticeable change in the hash.
E.g. see the properties listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: Can I add a topic from another discipline (e.g., Law) to an answered question?  How? Thank you.

Comment: @GAS4 What do you mean by "add a topic"?

Comment: My question is currently under the topic hash function. I wanted to add the topic law, so that people from that group will see the question.

Comment: @GAS4 I don't think [law] is a tag that exists on Math.SE, unfortunately.

Comment: I know, It’s on a different stack exchange site. I just thought there might be a way to copy it onto that site by using the topics. But I guess not. No problem. Thank you.

Comment: You can ask the question on another site of the stackoverflow network too. It is good practice to cite the original posting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. People have created examples of this for many popular has functions. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224113/examples-of-hash-collisions)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, different files can produce the same hash value. As you say, a hash function goes from a "big" discrete space $\mathcal{X}$ to a smaller image space $\mathcal{Y}$, and is thus many-to-one.

A *good* hash function, however, will take images "as uniformly distributed as possible" on $\mathcal{Y}$, in order to minimize the probability (over the input) that such a collision occurs.

(For many applications, one would also ask that the hash function be "hard to reverse-engineer" -- see [the crypto paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Properties) on the Wikipedia article.)

Comment: Thank for confirming this. In the legal community, hash codes are generally taken as being unique identifiers.  See for example, http://www.ca5.uscourts.gov/opinions/pub/17/17-41116-CR0.pdf. I think it would be helpful to articulate, at the appropriate technical level, the point  made in your second paragraph, regarding good hash functions.

Comment: @GAS4 This is what's roughly explained [in this other paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity). One more formal way to capture it (with no randomness in the choice of the input $x$ ("the file"), but instead in how the hash function is chosen (at the beginning of the program, randomly from a small-ish family of hash functions $\mathcal{H}$) is captured by the concept of [universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).

Comment: Basically, if you have a family $\mathcal{H}$ of hash functions from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$, the *universal hashing* requirement asks that for any two (arbitrary, worst-case) different inputs $x,x'\in\mathcal{X}$. $$\Pr_{h\in \mathcal{H}}[ h(x) = h(x') ] \leq \frac{1}{|\mathcal{Y}|}$$ where the probability is over the (uniformly random) choice of $h$ from $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Note that such a guarantee is for **all** $x\neq x'$, so even if $x$ only differs from $x'$ by a single bit, the hash should differ with high probability. @GAS4

Answer (score 1):

Yes. At least for the common hash functions, different files can produce the same hash, because those hash functions return byte arrays **of constant length**.

This is easily proven by the fact that there is an infinite number of possible files, and only a limited number of hashes. For example, for SHA1 there are $2^{160}$ possible hashes, for SHA512 $2^{512}$, etc. (And obviously there is an infinite number of files. E.g. start with "0", and add another "0" ad infinitum.)

But it might be possible to construct a hash function **of variable length** for which the answer would be no. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2679505/586550) for some ideas on how to do that. Though that would depend on calling a variable output-length function a hash function.